Transaction Builder - JSON file format
I'm trying to send a batch transfer of funds using the Transaction Builder. I don't want to manually enter each wallet address and the value. I see an option to "Drag and drop a JSON file"
What should the JSON file format be? Thanks!


This answer might be helpful.
